# Will I be notified if Canonical is required to disclose my personal information?

Tags: canonical

In the Canonical [privacy policy](http://www.canonical.com/aboutus/privacypolicy) terms is mentioned under:

> **What do we do with the information we collect:**
>
> To comply with legal and regulatory requirements (including responding to court orders, subpoenas and to prevent crime). These special circumstances may require us to disclose personal information.

Will I be informed about any disclosure of my personal information?

Comment: Yes it includes the NSA and no you probably won't be notified.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the media. Here are some quotes:

> "Recipients of such legal orders are barred from publicly comment on them."
>
> "Because the government has barred Lavabit from disclosing the nature of its demands, we still don't know what information the government is seeking, or why it's seeking it," said Ben Wizner, a national security lawyer for the ACLU.

[Source: NBC News](http://investigations.nbcnews.com/_news/2013/08/13/20008036-lavabitcom-owner-i-could-be-arrested-for-resisting-surveillance-order?lite)

If the NSA asked any tech company on matters of national security to provide information on users, this tech company is likely to be banned from making this public.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to a world of intelligence agencies like the NSA, secret services and other non-democratic institutions that change the law as they see fit and don't play by the rules anyway.

If you dislike such a post privacy world, then you should improve the implementation of democracy in your country. No matter in which country you live. Because that is the main issue here.

Sorry for speaking so bluntly, but intellegence agencies are the biggest threat to freedom, peace, privacy and democracy.